# Finding a href value with Regex

Tags: regex, search, find

I have a document with the following code inside

```
<link rel="next" type="application/atom+xml" href="https://xxxxxxxx.com?page=2"/>
```

Is there some regex that will look for a link tag with the rel of 'next' and get me the href value? This is far beyond my regex skills.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is not recommended to use regex for parsing HTML. You may try regex only if the `link` tag will be formatted in a specific way. Else you will see many different cases falling through regex.

Answer (score 1):

This type parsing shouldn't really be done from regex as unexpected nature of HTML can break the regex anytime.

Consider this DOM based code for this job:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument; 
$dom->loadXML(
  '<link rel="next" type="application/atom+xml" href="https://xxxxxxxx.com?page=2"/>'); 
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom); 
$nodelist = $xpath->query("//link[contains(@rel, 'next')]");
for($i=0; $i < $nodelist->length; $i++) {
    $node = $nodelist->item($i);
    echo $node->getAttribute('href') . "\n";
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
https://xxxxxxxx.com?page=2
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
href=[\'"]?([^\'" >]+)
```